# Xamarin.Forms Index was out of range exception sometimes showing up, but not always, How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get a new page shown depending on the selectedIndex in Xamarin.Forms.

```
public void NavigateToNextPage()
        {
            try
            {
                Result selected = lvwQuesions.SelectedItem as Result;

                if (selected != null)
                {
                    Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailQuizMasterPage(selected));
                    lvwQuesions.SelectedItem = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This code **works most of the time**, but sometimes (I can't repcoduce effectively) my app crashes and I get the "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter name:index" exception.

```
private void lvwQuesions_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateToNextPage();
    }
```

this is where i call my function. I don't really know where i'm trying to access anything by index so thiss error comes as a surprise.

Also this is a school project so i'm very new to Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Try debugging it. I cannot reproduce this.You need to provide more info.BUT this should be an obvious error. You see if you give an array of any type a negative index. You will get an IndexOutOfRange exception. int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3}. Then if try sth like this=> array[-1], i get your exception.

Comment: See what values are passed from you form. Also use your try catch to log your selected value.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it. i had two types of "questions": multiple choice and true/false(boolean) who had -as IncorrectAnswer- a list of either 3 or 1 strings. On the DetailQuizMasterPage, i didn't handle boolean type questions so it gave me the index error.